# How to import GLUT in Haskell script file

Tags: opengl, haskell, graphics, glut, hugs

I get an error when i try to import GLUT package

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
```

---

The error i am getting is **:**
[image: error]

I don't know how to use Graphics in haskell,

Tell me how i can import GLUT package if it says WinHugs can't find **`Graphics.UI.GLUT`** package.

**Update:** It would be really nice to get a video link, to understand it fast.

Comment: You need to install a package before trying to use it. Have you tried to run `cabal install GLUT`?

Comment: Sorry but i am using WinHugs on Windows 7, How i can install GLUT on Windows

Comment: While someone will always argue how much better Hugs is as an education tool, GHC is quite undisputedly the canonical choice if you want to do anything "real". So I shouldn't even start trying to get something nontrivial such as Glut working on Hugs, if I were you. (Nor on Windows, for that matter, but...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinHugs is really old, and hasn't been updated since 2006. Please switch to the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/) which uses the GHC compiler instead. If you do that, your code will work out-of-the-box, because the GLUT package is included in the Platform by default.

Comment: No, you have to compile the package from source, which is quite complicated if you use Hugs and Windows. I recommend that you don't use Hugs and just use the Haskell Platform. If you really need to use Hugs, you need to install a C compiler like MinGW, a UNIX-like environment like MSYS, compile the `Cabal` library and the `cabal-install` program, then download a version of the GLUT C library (Like freeglut) including headers, and install the `GLUT` library with `cabal install GLUT`, specifying the location to your GLUT headers and libraries. Please just use Haskell Platform!

Comment: Thanks dflemstr, Your suggestion for Haskell Platform was really valuable.

Answer (score 3):

This means you are using **WinHugs with minimal collection of libraries** and that's why you are not facing any problem with `import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL` but as you said `import Graphics.UI.GLUT` is not working in your WinHugs, this means you need to add `GLUT` package in your WinHugs libraries.

This is a [link](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/downloads/2006-09/hugs98-plus-Sep2006.tar.gz)  through which you can get the WinHugs, other programs, and a **large collection of libraries**.

- Some of the library packages are built only if the system you're
  building on is set up for compilation with certain C libraries. In
  particular you get the Haskell X11 and HGL packages only if X11
  libraries are available to you, and the OpenGL, **`GLUT`**, OpenAL and ALUT packages
  only if the corresponding C libraries are already present.

Answer (score 3):

So, After too much research and study I finally got my solution from myself.
Graphics in Haskell is not a big deal if you are using **Haskell Platform**, It would be really a tedious task and most probably impossible to work with graphics in **WinHugs**.

So you should first download & install haskell platform on your machine then you have to download and install(copy) `GLUT` packages in your system folder and this will enable you to use them.
For more information you can watch my own youtube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcDGbIvIl9w&feature=c4-overview&list=UUhX96dLnXOgmXbQ7lA6LQIQ) which I've uploaded on my youtube account for quick instruction guide.

Comment: Since I can't post videos on Stack overflow - This video tutorial would be really beneficial for you.